# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in reducer

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx, angular8

I am getting below error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

**reducer file**:

```
import * as PfaAction from '../actions/profilefunctionarea.actions';
import { Action, createSelector, createFeatureSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
import { AppAction } from 'src/app/app.action';
import { Pfa } from '../shared/pfa';

export interface State {
    data: Pfa[];
}

const initialState: State = {
    data: [],
};

export function reducer(state = initialState, action: AppAction) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PfaAction.GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA:
            return {
                ...state,
                action: PfaAction.GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA
            }
    }
}

export const getPfaState = createFeatureSelector < State > ('pfas');
export const getAllPfas = createSelector(getPfaState, (state: State) => state.data); <-- here getting error
```

**component.ts:**

```
import { Pfa } from 'src/app/ngrx/shared/pfa';

pfas: Observable<Pfa[]>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.pfas = this.store.select(getAllPfas);
}
```

**component.html:**

```
<select *ngFor="let pfa of pfas | async">
   <option value="pfa.id">{{pfa.area}}</option>
</select>
```

**Pfa.ts:**

```
export class Pfa {
    id: number;
    area: string;
}
```

**action.ts:**

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ProfileFunctionArea } from 'src/app/_interface/profilefucntionarea.module';
import { Pfa } from '../shared/pfa';

export const GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA = '[ALL] Profile Function Area';
export const GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA_SUCCESS = '[ALL] Profile Function Area Success';
export const GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA_ERROR = '[ALL] Profile Function Area Error';

export class GetProfileFunctionArea implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA;
}

export class GetProfileFunctionAreaSuccess implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA_SUCCESS;
    constructor(public payload: Pfa[]) { }
}

export class GetProfileFunctionAreaError implements Action {
    readonly type = GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA_ERROR;
    constructor(public payload: Error) { }
}
```

**effects.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class ProfileFunctionAreaEffects {
    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private ps: ProfileService) { }

    @Effect() GetProfileFunctionArea$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe( ofType(PfaAction.GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA),
    switchMap(() => this.ps.GetProfileFunctionAreaGet()),
    map(items => new GetProfileFunctionAreaSuccess(items)), <-- getting error here
    catchError((err) => [new GetProfileFunctionAreaError(err)]));

}
```

Comment: Could you please add some more info as from where the error is emerging, what you are trying to achieve etc. Apart from this, I haven't worked on ngrx and stuff but I see the `.data` is accessed in reducer file `createSelector` function. So probably `state` is undefined. But, question has to be more elaborative, in order for someone to answer.

Comment: @kiranghule27 when trying to get list in component.html file, I am getting that error!

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is wrong

```
        return {
            ...state,
            action: PfaAction.GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA
        }
```

You should be return

```
        return {
            ...state,
            data: [] // add your array here
        }
```

Comment: let me try this.

Comment: which array? Pfa[]<--this?

Comment: Array of data come from your payload. Do you understand how redux work ?

Comment: I am trying to understand but not getting it

Comment: added both file code, but I am getting error in `effects.ts`, this line `map(items => new GetProfileFunctionAreaSuccess(items)),` for items

Comment: erorr is `Argument of type 'FunctionArea[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pfa[]'.
  Type 'FunctionArea' is not assignable to type 'Pfa'.
    Property 'id' is optional in type 'FunctionArea' but required in type 'Pfa'.`

Comment: can help with??

Answer (score 0):

A reducer should always return state, in the snippet the reducer will only return state for `PfaAction.GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA` and will return `undefined` for every other action that is dispatch. This is because an action will be dispatched to all reducers.

To fix this, add a `default` case:

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: AppAction) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case PfaAction.GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA:
            return {
                ...state,
                action: PfaAction.GET_PROFILEFUNCTIONAREA
            }

       // add this
       default:
          return state;
    }
}
```